# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

XPath doesn't work on below path code.

**HTML**

```html
<span class="voter_details">
 <h4 class="v_msg" id="v_msg" style="font-size: 14px;margin-bottom:25px;">Hi, you are here XXXfor  in a while, kindly enter your name!</h4>
 <input value="" placeholder="Enter your Name" type="text" id="v" name="v" class="form-control name_box" maxlength="20">
 </span>
```

**Error**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='v']"}
```

**Code**

```
driver.find_element(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='v']")).send_keys('random.choice(list)')
```

Comment: You're using `find_element` two times

Answer (score 1):

Use following `xpath` to access the input element.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter your Name'][@id='v']").send_keys('Ashwani')
```

OR You can use WebdriverWait to wait for the element to be clickable and send then enter the value.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Enter your Name'][@id='v']"))).send_keys('Ashwani')
```

To execute that you need to have following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: why don't you use `and` in the XPath? Is there a reason you use `[][]` instead?

Comment: @MosheSlavin : No there is no reason to use [][] this but I prefrer to do that.If use and also give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.name_box#v[placeholder='Enter your Name']"))).send_keys(random.choice(list))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control name_box' and @id='v'][@placeholder='Enter your Name']"))).send_keys(random.choice(list))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="uname"]"}
```

I got same error while I was working with Selenium.
The problem is slow internet/big website. Try adding explicit or implicit delay or you may import time module and add time.sleep before clicking/sending keys